# Is there a mobile Safari fullscreen Javascript event?

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, dom-events

I can't even find people asking questions about this, which is baffling to me.

Does mobile Safari fire a Javascript event when the user enters fullscreen mode (iOS 6)? I am currently resizing my document `onorientationchange` and need to do so in full screen mode as well, but can't find ANYTHING about this.

Comment: iOS safari has a full screen mode? Are you meaning when you turn the device from portrait to landscape?

Comment: I mean when you are in landscape mode, and then press the full screen button...

Comment: @RoatinMarth http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57513848-285/how-to-use-safaris-full-screen-mode-on-ios-6/

Comment: Play with `standalone" in window.navigator &&
!window.navigator.standalone`

Comment: A workaround would be to set an interval which checks window.height and fires an custom event as soon as the height changes.

Comment: This is a new feature - and not the same thing as "standalone" mode.  I'm noticing some issues when turning it on though.. absolute/fixed positioned elements & backgrounds with background-size:cover do not seem to reset their coordinates properly when you enter this mode.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this might explain why no one is asking about it:

`window.onresize`. Duh!

Comment: Oh boy, this is problematic though. When you scroll to the edge of the page and you see the overflow area (gray textured area), `resize` event is firing, which kind of makes sense, but is also pretty stupid. In my case this is causing crazy jerking of the page resizing for each `resize` event fired, which I assume is one for every `mousemove`.